# Suppress Clojure errors in Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm writing a web application in Clojure and sometimes I have an error at a specific route. I don't have the wrap stacktraces middleware running. But it shows the error still, not a stack trace but just a one line of the error like so and so function, invalid arity, etc.

It seems like the function is returning a string that gets returned as the body in compojure.

Is there a way to hide these errors in production?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty/HttpKit serve a 500 if an exception is not caught.

Maybe you have some other catch+print middleware running?

To hide the error in production, I'd fix it :)